# How to return string slice after format macro in rust

Tags: string, rust, reference, ownership

I have an enum `MyEnum` with `as_str` method implemented.
What I want to do is to make it so that I could return `&str` formatted with `SPACING` from `match` arm.

For example instead of `"ONE"` I would get `format!("{SPACING}ONE{SPACING}")`, but the problem is `format` macro returns owned string and the attempt to return a reference results in `cannot return reference to temporary value` error.

```
enum MyEnum {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
}

const SPACING: &'static str = " ";

impl MyEnum {
    fn as_str(&self) -> &str {
        match self {
            MyEnum::One => "ONE",
            MyEnum::Two => "TWO",
            MyEnum::Three => "THREE",
        }
    }
}
```

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to format string literal and return a string slice?
2. Also I'm a bit confused about what owns string literal inside `match` arms, I guess it's `static` and exists throughout the entire program execution  time or is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot do that. As you explained yourself formatted `String` is a local variable and returning reference to it would result in a dangling reference, which rust strictly forbids. You must returned owned `String` instead. Consider implementing `Display` which will automatically provide implementation of `ToString`.
2. You are correct. Every string literal in rust is a `&'static str`.